# Open a new window on click with ember

Tags: ember.js

How can I open a new window when the user clicks on a link?

I have tried adding `target="_blank"` and bindAttr but it doesn't work.

The code that doesn't work:

```
<a target="_blank" {{action goToSettings href=true}}>App Settings</a>
```

or

```
<a {{bindAttr target="_blank"}} {{action goToSettings href=true}}>App Settings</a>
```

And this is the html output from the first example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#/settings" data-ember-action="5">App Settings</a>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show us the output html of your first example?

Comment: You're actually calling a function in your application. What does `goToSettings` do? The way this is set up it will never open a new window unless you explicitly write the code in that function. If you want this to be a link, set the an URL (a route?) to the `href` property

Comment: Yeah exactly this function is in my router: goToSettings:  Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.settings'),

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. send an action, and in the javascript that handles the action, call
   `window.open(...)` to open a new window to a particular URL
2. Don't use an action and instead make it a static link or if you need to
   dynamically vary the target URL, use `<a target="_blank" {{bindAttr
   href="yourBoundPropForTheUrl"}}>Click here</a>`

Comment: The problem with the first approach is that I only want to open a new window in a specific case. For all other actions I'd like it to be in the same window. I am not sure I understand the second option. what would be the yourBoundPropForTheUrl"?

Comment: In the first approach, you can still exercise some conditional logic to decide whether to open a new window or transition to another state. For the second option, the idea is that `yourBoundPropForTheUrl` would be a property that resolves to the URL that you want to open.

Comment: If you are not yet on a version of Ember with support for this in LinkView, you may also be pondering how to generate a URL valid for Ember's route logic. As _also_ provided by @LukeMelia on his answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513081/how-to-generate-url-for-a-route-in-ember-js), you can access the router to generate the URL based on parameters similar to what you would use with `transitionToRoute`. Here's an example from within a controller action:

`this.get('target').router.generate('item', item.topic_id, item.id);`

Answer (score 3):

This has been added to [LinkView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkView.html#property_target), and therefore is now supported directly in `{{link-to}}`.

Pull request is at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4718