# How to generate url for a route in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

I am wondering how is possible to generate url for a given route.

## My scenario

I have list of calls (db entity) and user can select several calls and share them with other people via email.

After submition of selected calls is created db row with hash and by relation contains selected calls. Now I need generate link which can be sended by e-mail. This link is not the same route as list of call's route.

So the question is: **Is it possible to generate url by route and params in Ember.js?** Thank you.

Comment: This is outside of the ember application?

Comment: No inside the Ember app

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`Router#generate`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/b186e6e3fa000f1960c8837530dff7416a1e7e0a/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L294) which delegates to the [router.js library](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/blob/6caee7215527607970df5d5021ea3421f0c1b159/lib/router/router.js#L258).

### [Ember 2.5 Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sulusudumu/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' }, function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });
});

App.Post = Ember.Object.extend();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      App.Post.create({
        id: 5,
        title: 'I am post 5'
      }),
      App.Post.create({
        id: 6,
        title: 'I am post 6'
      }),
      App.Post.create({
        id: 7,
        title: 'I am post 7'
      })];
  },
  actions: {
    showUrl: function(post) {
      alert(this.router.generate('post.edit', post));
    }
  }
});
```

### [Ember 1.3 Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ecEYixo/2/edit?html,js,output)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' }, function(){
    this.route('edit');
  });
});

App.Post = Ember.Object.extend();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      App.Post.create({
        id: 5,
        title: 'I am post 5'
      }),
      App.Post.create({
        id: 6,
        title: 'I am post 6'
      }),
      App.Post.create({
        id: 7,
        title: 'I am post 7'
      })];
  },
  actions: {
    showUrl: function(post) {
      alert(this.router.generate('post.edit', post));
    }
  }
});
```

This is what the `{{#link-to ...}}` helper uses under the hood.

Comment: Excellent, I looked into LinkView and found this also, but thank you anyway.

Comment: How to use this inside a helper??

Comment: Your answer is for Ember 1.x and doesn't work for 2.x. Is it possible in Ember 2.x too?

Comment: @Envek I've added a JSBin link to an example with Ember 2.5. It still appears to work.

Comment: @LukeMelia thank you for help. It also works if click on $E sign at the route in Ember Inspector and execute code like ```$E.router.generate('crews.edit', {id: 10002, queryParams: {stopped: true}})```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in any Ember.js class with the [`RouterService`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/RouterService). It is available since Ember.js 2.15 and in 3.x. Routing functions are no longer confined to `Route`s.

### Ember 2.15, 3.x Example

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  router: service(),

  actions: {
    showUrl(post) {
      alert(this.get('router').urlFor('post.edit', post));
    }
  }
});
```