# Call Router.generate from a helper

Tags: ember.js

I need to generate the url for given route from a helper.

[How to generate url for a route in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513081/how-to-generate-url-for-a-route-in-ember-js) pointed me to use the generate function. And yes it works as i need (Checked the functionality by making application route global). But i am not sure how to call it from inside a helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were in a good direction, so you mainly solved this problem. :) There are two type of helper in Ember a simple function helper and the [Class Based Helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_class-based-helpers). We will use a Class Based Helper in this case.

As you have seen in your linked example, we need access to the main Router. We can do this with `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main')`. (`Ember.getOwner()` [exists from v2.3](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_injected-container-access), before v2.3 use `this.container.lookup('router:main')`)

For example, you have this map in your `router.js`:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('post', {path: '/:post_id'});
  });
});
```

And if you create a helper for example with the name of `url-for` your template could contain these lines:

```
{{url-for 'about'}}
{{url-for 'posts'}}
{{url-for 'posts.post' 2}}
```

And your Class Based Helper could be the following:

```
// app/helpers/url-for.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.extend({
  router: Ember.computed(function() {
    return Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main');
  }),

  compute([routeName, ...routeParams]) {
    let router = this.get('router');

    return Ember.isEmpty(routeParams) ?
      router.generate(routeName) : router.generate(routeName, routeParams[0]);
  }
});
```

**[Demo on Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/edb4cd31c0a6092681915b16eb6344c8?openFiles=helpers.url-for.js%2C)**

Comment: `container.lookup` did the job. Thank you.